# Manifest file doesn't contain the correct activites in my project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, android-manifest

[image]basically, I imported a project from a laptop. This apparently worked alright, but the default project files were still there. I deleted these. However the manifest file didn't change/update for the new activities from the imported project.
Is there a way to update the manifest file through Eclipse?? (I have already tried cleaning the project, to no success). It currently only contains the single default activity.
Or do I need to manually update it, by adding entries for each activity??

Thanks for the help!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this manually. Eclipse don't have any option for that.

Comment: OK, thanks. That shouldn't be too difficult, just a bit boring... :) Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yes, You can copy from your old project

Comment: got there quite quickly. for future readers: copy across the contents of the Manifest XML file into your current Manifest XML.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Eclipse imports the whole project including the manifest. I get all my changes at once. Do check if you have some old files in the directory, as Eclipse may skip the particular file then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each activity in manifest manually. 
It is not automated and eclipse don't have option / tool for this.

In debug, you always get a message and suggestion for nondeclared activity in manifest.

Comment: There is option of add activity automatically in Manifest.xml in Eclipse. File->New Other->Android Activity

Comment: Yes, but not imported. Then he must manually enter all missing activities.